# How to save Second Dimension Of Hash In Order Perl

Tags: perl

How I can save these Arrays into this Hash Of Arrays in order, not following alphabetically order, just save according to the Arrays.

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
 - stackoverflow won't allow me to post because not enough details, so I did this -

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use warnings;
use strict;
use Tie::IxHash;
use Data::Dumper;

my @NAME= qw(AA AB AC BA BB BC CA CB CC AA AB AC BA BB BC CA CB CC AA AB AC BA BB BC CA CB CC AD CD CE CF BD BE);
my @FAMILY= qw(A A A B B B C C C A A A B B B C C C A A A B B B C C C A C C C B B);
my @COMMUNITY= qw(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 1 1);

tie my %COMMUNITY_FAMILY_NAME,'Tie::IxHash' ;

push @{ $COMMUNITY_FAMILY_NAME{ $COMMUNITY[$_] }{ $FAMILY[$_] } }, $NAME[$_]  for 0 .. $#NAME;
print Dumper(\%COMMUNITY_FAMILY_NAME);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '0' => {
                   'A' => [
                            'AA',
                            'AB',
                            'AC',
                            'AD'
                          ],
                   'C' => [
                            'CA',
                            'CB',
                            'CC'
                          ],
                   'B' => [
                            'BA',
                            'BB',
                            'BC'
                          ]
                 },
          '1' => {
                   'A' => [
                            'AA',
                            'AB',
                            'AC'
                          ],
                   'C' => [
                            'CA',
                            'CB',
                            'CC'
                          ],
                   'B' => [
                            'BA',
                            'BB',
                            'BC',
                            'BD',
                            'BE'
                          ]
                 },
          '2' => {
                   'A' => [
                            'AA',
                            'AB',
                            'AC'
                          ],
                   'C' => [
                            'CA',
                            'CB',
                            'CC',
                            'CD',
                            'CE',
                            'CF'
                          ],
                   'B' => [
                            'BA',
                            'BB',
                            'BC'
                          ]
                 }
        };
```

Expected Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '0' => {
                   'A' => [
                            'AA',
                            'AB',
                            'AC',
                            'AD'
                          ],
                   'B' => [
                            'BA',
                            'BB',
                            'BC'
                          ]
                   'C' => [
                            'CA',
                            'CB',
                            'CC'
                          ],
                 },
          '1' => {
                   'A' => [
                            'AA',
                            'AB',
                            'AC'
                          ],
                   'B' => [
                            'BA',
                            'BB',
                            'BC',
                            'BD',
                            'BE'
                   'C' => [
                            'CA',
                            'CB',
                            'CC'
                          ],

                          ]
                 },
          '2' => {
                   'A' => [
                            'AA',
                            'AB',
                            'AC'
                          ],
                   'B' => [
                            'BA',
                            'BB',
                            'BC'
                          ]
                   'C' => [
                            'CA',
                            'CB',
                            'CC',
                            'CD',
                            'CE',
                            'CF'
                          ],
                 }
        };
```

Comment: Do you want each value in the tied hash to also be tied to an IxHash instead of being a normal hashref?

Comment: When dumping data with [`Data::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) you can provide `Sortkeys` option to have keys sorted.

Comment: @el.pescado, I need to maintain the order of the FAMILY's array in the hash.

Comment: @Shawn, yes, you can said so too.

Answer (score 7):

Your subhashes are not tied to `Tie::IxHash`, and thus they are plain/unordered. You can change that by `tie` every subhash before usage.

```
# push @{ $COMMUNITY_FAMILY_NAME{ $COMMUNITY[$_] }{ $FAMILY[$_] } }, $NAME[$_]  for 0 .. $#NAME;

for (0 .. $#NAME) {
    my $href = $COMMUNITY_FAMILY_NAME{ $COMMUNITY[$_] } ||= do {
        tie my %hash, 'Tie::IxHash';
        \%hash;
    };
    push @{ $href->{ $FAMILY[$_] } }, $NAME[$_];
}
```

Comment: I thought the whole hash have been tied. Thank you for this knowledge.

Comment: how do tie if I have another subhash, third level subhash?

Comment: Check https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::Autotie, also https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=485306

Answer (score 5):

The issue you're running into is that a tied hash only affects one level - each value of a tied hash is just whatever you store in it, which usually is a normal perl value. That means if you want a multi-dimensional tied hash, both the top level variable has to be tied, and any values stored in it (In this case, hashrefs) as well.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use Tie::IxHash;

tie my %hash, 'Tie::IxHash';
tie %{$hash{"b"}}, 'Tie::IxHash';
tie %{$hash{"c"}}, 'Tie::IxHash';

$hash{"b"}->{"b"} = [ qw/1 2 3/ ];
$hash{"b"}->{"a"} = [ qw/4 5 6/ ];
$hash{"c"}->{"d"} = [ qw/7 8 9/ ];
$hash{"c"}->{"c"} = [ qw/10 11 12/ ];

print Dumper(\%hash);
```